# It is possible to add Windows Service to an Existing project?

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio-2015, windows-services

I've created a Windows Form Application in C# and I added a Window Service on it. The problem is every time I started the Service after installing it, I always get the `Error 1053 the service did not respond to the start or control request`. But after creating a new project and Select Windows Service and Installed and Run it there's no error and the Service is Starting correctly.

So do I have to create a Separate project for Windows Service or I am just missing something?

My target Framework is 4.5.2 and I am planning to have UDP and TCP function inside my Windows Service.

Comment: "So do I have to create a Separate project for Windows Service" *No*. "or I am just missing something?" *Yes*

Comment: Is there anything I have to configure? What do you think is missing? This is the first time I work in Windows Service. I learn on creating Windows Service base on tutorial I found. I always get the tutorial with windows service but no tutorial with Windows Form Application.

Comment: I don't know. How would we reproduce your issue?

Comment: Hmmm.... If empty project work OK... Start of service is limited in time. I don't remember, 30s? 60s? harder algoritm move to new thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling ServiceBase.Run() from Main() is what makes an application a service rather than a normal application.  If you created a project using the Windows Service template, but took away the call to ServiceBase.Run(), the result would be a normal application rather than a service.  (Probably a *broken* application, but an application nonetheless.)

Under the hood, ServiceBase.Run() calls [StartServiceCtrlDispatcher()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms686324(v=vs.85).aspx), which calls the internal ServiceBase.ServiceMainCallback() function, which calls your OnStart() function.  So if you don't call Run() there will be no call to OnStart() and your service won't do anything.

The StartServiceCtrlDispatcher() function is also indirectly responsible for calling OnStop() and all the other related methods.  Basically, it's the core of the service, and without it nothing will work.  Also, of course, if you don't call it Windows will eventually notice that the control dispatcher hasn't started, assume that the process has hung, and kill it.  That's what error 1053 means.

While it *is* possible to incorporate both a service and an application in a single executable, it isn't trivial to get it working properly.  It is also an unusual approach, not often used.  Unless you have a compelling reason to avoid doing so, I'd recommend that you use a separate project for your service.

Comment: so, I need to create 2 project? one for Service and one for Windows Form. Is it really recommended when it comes to windows service to create a separate project rather than adding it on existing windows form app?

Comment: If the windows service is in a separate project, and I have some method in there that I wanted to call later,  can I call it? I'm afraid if no, I have some function to call in my service.

Comment: You could move the common functionality to a library.

Comment: It is becoming more difficult for me. OK thanks! I'll try to do this, I'll update you if it is done and mark your answer as correct.